# Apple Mail - assigning keyboard shortcuts for different email account inboxes?

Tags: apple-mail

While cmd-1 goes to the inbox in Mac Mail, I would like more fine-grained control over which inbox I am viewing via keyboard shortcut. Is it possible to create keyboard shortcuts for each email account inbox?

Answer (score 0):

I found a decent work around for this: items in the mailbox sidebar can be dragged to the *favorites bar*, and items can be removed from it as well. cmd-1 through cmd-9 map to the items placed in the favorites bar.